# Haskell problema con la signature en el numero de parámetros

Tags: haskell, signature

Estoy tratando de demostrar que las pruebas de un código haskell son deficientes a pesar de mi casi nulo conocimiento en haskell.

Este es mi código actual:

```
module FizzBuzz(fizzbuzz) where

import Data.Array

fizzbuzz :: Int -> [String]
fizzbuzz n = subArray(0,n,["1", "2", "Fizz", "4", "Buzz", "Fizz", "7", "8", "Fizz", "Buzz", "11", "Fizz", "13", "14", "FizzBuzz", "16", "17", "Fizz", "19", "Buzz", "Fizz", "22", "23", "Fizz", "Buzz", "26", "Fizz", "28", "29", "FizzBuzz", "31", "32", "Fizz", "34", "Buzz", "Fizz", "37", "38", "Fizz", "Buzz", "41", "Fizz", "43", "44", "FizzBuzz", "46", "47", "Fizz", "49", "Buzz", "Fizz", "52", "53", "Fizz", "Buzz", "56", "Fizz", "58", "59", "FizzBuzz", "61", "62", "Fizz", "64", "Buzz", "Fizz", "67", "68", "Fizz", "Buzz", "71", "Fizz", "73", "74", "FizzBuzz", "76", "77", "Fizz", "79", "Buzz", "Fizz", "82", "83", "Fizz", "Buzz", "86", "Fizz", "88", "89", "FizzBuzz", "91", "92", "Fizz", "94", "Buzz", "Fizz", "97", "98", "Fizz", "Buzz"])

subArray :: Int -> Int -> Array -> Array
subArray i j a = listArray (0,j-i) $ map (a!) [i..j]
```

Me marca el error

> ```
>  FizzBuzz.hs:8:27:
>    Expecting two more arguments to `Array'
>    Expected a type, but `Array' has kind `* -> * -> *'
>    In the type signature for `subArray':
>      subArray :: Int -> Int -> Array -> Array
> ```

La prueba unitaria a la que apunto es:

```
module FizzBuzzTest where
import FizzBuzz(fizzbuzz)
import Test.Hspec

main :: IO ()
main = hspec $ describe "Fizzbuzz" $ do
  it "Should fizzify 10 numbers correctly" $ do
    let expected = ["1","2","Fizz","4","Buzz","Fizz","7","8","Fizz","Buzz"]
    fizzbuzz 10 `shouldBe` expected
```

Answer (score 1):

Tienes varios errores.

El primero es cuando anotas el tipo de los arrays en las firmas de la función. `Array i e` es un constructor de tipos (con índices en `i` y valores en `e`) que toma dos tipos y devuelve un tipo concreto. Por ejemplo, `Array Int String` es un tipo de array cuyos índices son enteros y cuyos valores son strings.

Por lo tanto, la firma de tu función `subArray` debería ser la siguiente:

```
subArray :: Int -> Int -> Array Int a -> Array Int a
subArray i j a = listArray (0,j-i) $ map (a!) [i..j]
```

De forma más general, el tipo de los índices podría ser cualquiera que fuese enumerable, numérico e indexable:

```
subArray :: (Ix i, Enum i, Num i) => i -> i -> Array i a -> Array i a
subArray i j a = listArray (0,j-i) $ map (a!) [i..j]
```

El segundo error está en tu función `fizzbuzz`. El tipo que devuelve debería ser un array, no una lista (`fizzbuzz :: Int -> Array Int String`). La llamada a la función `subArray` no tiene la notación correcta, dado que le estás pasando una 3-tupla en lugar de llamarla con tres argumentos (hay que eliminar paréntesis y comas). Por último, la función `subArray` espera un array como entrada, no una lista, así que hay que convertir la lista a un array.

```
fizzbuzz :: Int -> Array Int String
fizzbuzz n = subArray 0 n (listArray (0,100) ["1", "2", "Fizz", "4", "Buzz", "Fizz", "7", "8", "Fizz", "Buzz", "11", "Fizz", "13", "14", "FizzBuzz", "16", "17", "Fizz", "19", "Buzz", "Fizz", "22", "23", "Fizz", "Buzz", "26", "Fizz", "28", "29", "FizzBuzz", "31", "32", "Fizz", "34", "Buzz", "Fizz", "37", "38", "Fizz", "Buzz", "41", "Fizz", "43", "44", "FizzBuzz", "46", "47", "Fizz", "49", "Buzz", "Fizz", "52", "53", "Fizz", "Buzz", "56", "Fizz", "58", "59", "FizzBuzz", "61", "62", "Fizz", "64", "Buzz", "Fizz", "67", "68", "Fizz", "Buzz", "71", "Fizz", "73", "74", "FizzBuzz", "76", "77", "Fizz", "79", "Buzz", "Fizz", "82", "83", "Fizz", "Buzz", "86", "Fizz", "88", "89", "FizzBuzz", "91", "92", "Fizz", "94", "Buzz", "Fizz", "97", "98", "Fizz", "Buzz"])
```

Por ejemplo:

```
*FizzBuzz> fizzbuzz 3
array (0,3) [(0,"1"),(1,"2"),(2,"Fizz"),(3,"4")]
```

Si esperas que la función `fizzbuzz` devuelva una lista en lugar de un array, puedes usar la función `elems`:

```
elems :: Array i e -> [e]
```

Comment: por la prueba unitaria creo que se espera una lista, puedes ver el ejercicio aquí: https://www.codewars.com/kata/fizz-buzz/train/haskell

Comment: Para lo que quieres probar posiblemente te valga con una solución del tipo `fizzbuzz = (flip take) ["1", "2", "Fizz", ...]`, o equivalentemente, `fizzbuzz n = take n ["1", "2", "Fizz", ...]`. Pero ten en cuenta que en esa plataforma además de los tests de ejemplo, luego hay que pasar otros tests privados, que probablemente pidan un número arbitrario/aleatorio de elementos de la secuencia.

Comment: bueno del código de fizzbuz que psiste en la respuesta, por la prueba unitaria veo que le mandan tipo Char ne vez de Int. 
fizzbuzz :: Char -> Array Int (Char -> Int) -> [String]
fizzbuzz n = subArray 0 (digitToInt (n)) (listArray (0,100) ["1", "2", "Fizz"...])